# how to remove a role scoped to a resource instance in rolify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I Implemented a user - membership - organization relations using:
I use rolify to implent the roles of user in organizations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    rolify
    has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :organizations, through: :memberships
end


class Membership < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    resourcify
    has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :memberships
end
```

Then, whenever I invoke def unjoin in OrganizationControllers:

```
def join
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])

    if @organization.users.exists?(current_user.id)
        flash[:notice] = 'Already a Member'
        redirect_to @organization
    else
        @organization.users << current_user
        current_user.add_role :member, @organization

        if current_user == @organization.users.last
           flash[:notice] = 'Successfully Joined In'
           redirect_to @organization
        else
           flash[:notice] = 'Unable to Join'
           redirect_to @organization
        end
    end
end

def unjoin      
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
    if @organization.users.exists?(current_user.id)

        current_user.remove_role :member, @organization         #Error 
        @organization.users.delete(current_user)

        if @organization.users.exists?(current_user.id)
            flash[:notice] = 'Unable to unjoin'
            redirect_to @organization
        else
            flash[:notice] = 'Successfully Unjoined'
            redirect_to @organization
        end
    else
        flash[:notice] = 'Not Yet A Member'
        redirect_to @organization
    end
 end
```

I get **NoMethodError in OrganizationsController#unjoin
undefined method `users' for #**, 
in line: **current_user.remove_role :member, @organization**

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `id` properly? the error is happening in previous line because `Organization.find(params[:id]) = nil`, also you need to pass `current_user` instead of `current_user.id`

Comment: yes, I have a line where: 
    def organization_params
        params.require(:organization).permit(:name)
    end

also, according to this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F

    exists?(conditions = :none) 

Returns true if a record exists in the table that matches the id or conditions given, or false otherwise.